# Fetch Day Wise Last previous 7 day Data using Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is query code

```
  $day7 = transaction::count('id')->whereDate('created_at', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString())
   ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(7)->toDateString())->where([['merchant_id' ,'=',$merchant_id]])->groupBy('created_date')->get();
```

when i use count() method insted of get it counts all transaction but in get it cannot work

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use count and get within the same query as they are performing different tasks. There is a Laravel method to query for the result between dates (`whereBetween`)

Maybe try something like:

```
$day7 = Transaction::whereBetween('created_at', [\Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString(), \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(7)->toDateString()])
    ->where('merchant_id', '=', $merchant_id)
    ->groupBy('created_date')
    ->count()
```

You should also look at the docs. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

this Query is work for me finally i found solution.

```
 $day7 =transaction::where('created_at', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::now())

   ->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(6))->where([['merchant_id' ,'=',$merchant_id]])->get()->groupBy(function($item) {
     return $item->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
   });
```